# Canned fruit vs fruit packed in shelf stable plastic packs

Tags: canning

I bought some fruit in Dole Fridge Pack *off of shelf* from store. It tasted surprisingly fresh. Is there a different method for fruit stored in shelf stable not refigerated plastic container vs fruit in cans. I though both were just different *types* of canning.

Comment: "fruit in plastic container" is pretty broad, do you have more detail, a picture…?. Supermarkets sell ready-to-eat, nothing done to it except to chop it for you, which you have to eat today. It tastes pretty much like fresh because it is pretty much like fresh. Canned food is super-heated to sterilise & lasts just short of forever.

Comment: @Tetsujin : As the question was about 'shelf stable' packaging, I suspect that it's either individually portion 'fruit cup' type packaging, or that it's the plastic jars of fruit that Dole and other companies have been producing for the last decade or so: https://dolesunshine.com/products/jarred-fruit

Comment: @Joe - question was edited after my comment, as I had requested. I'd guess that stuff is pasteurised, but it's not something I've ever investigated.